# "Месяц под косой блестит, а во лбу звезда горит"

Tags: литература, пушкин

Недавно задумалась: *а что это за странное описание **царевны Лебеди?***
Ну, насчет "звезды во лбу" я еще могу предположить: обруч со сверкающим камнем.
***А вот что за месяц под косой?*** Я что-то не припомню такого украшения в русской традиции.
Спасибо.

Comment: Обращу внимание на цитату из Откровения "И явилось на небе великое знамение: жена, облеченная в солнце; под ногами ее луна, а на главе ее венец из двенадцати звезд" (Откр 12.1). Нисколько не настаиваю, что именно это и есть первоисточник народного образа, но возможность хотя бы частичного влияния не исключаю.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я не отрицаю, сказанное Людмилой. 
Но есть и конкретное объяснение.
Я думаю, и звезда и месяц - это намек на древнерусские украшения, теменные и височные. 
Усерязи и колты соответственно ( http://www.larussie.narod.ru/odezhda/od03.htm ) 
"Под косой" - это вряд ли "бантик" на конце современной косы. Косы вероятнее  всего в виденье Пушкина были уложены в "стожок" за затылке или "котлетки" на ушах - по тогдашней моде. Специально посмотрел текст - нигде не говорится о длине косы.

Меня смущает только некоторый ахронизм этой идеи. Сказка-то ***народная***, а украшения - вроде как древнерусские. Но височные украшения были популярны и после, что-то мне вспоминаются портреты Гончаровой именно с такими "подвесками". Вот форму их не могу вспомнить.

ну да. Вот что-то подобное, только форма украшений другая.
http://www.rulex.ru/rpg/WebPict/fullpic/0038-002.jpg

А про день и ночь у Людмилы - все правильно. Не отрицаю.

*Кроме бурятов. Я вообще крепко сомневаюсь в таком тотеме. 
Я хорошо знаком с монгольской культурой, откуда вообще  у кочевых степняков-скотоводов сугубо водоплавающий тотем озерных стран? Гусь - я бы еще понял. А лебедя там днем с огнем не встретишь.*

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ! Мне он кажется самым убедительным!

Comment: Про день и ночь у Людмилы, только цитата из Пушкина.

Про лебедя у бурятов можно прочитать [здесь](http://vsemirniysledopyt.ru/b/172353/read) (главка сразу после карты-схемы распространения бурятских народных сказок.Лебедь - это тотем хори-бурят, а также бурятских родов ханьин и шарайд, проживающих в Иркутской области.

Comment: Бред какой-то...
Хотя "Рыбный" тотем - еще нелепее.
Вот монгольские тотемы - это я понимаю.
http://photo.argumenti.ru/Mongolia/82

Впрочем, про Монголию успел прочитать столько бреда, что даже и пересказывать не берусь. 
Спорить не буду, но все настолько противоречит моим представлениям о монголах... 

ЗЫ Кто не знает. Буряты - это монголы. "Внутри себя" они как-то себя различают, но это не для белого человека.  
Ладно, я завязываю, а то голый флуд уже пошел.

Comment: Буряты живут вокруг озера Байкал. Как раз странным было бы отсутствие у них сказок и тотемов на "водной" основе.

Comment: Буряты живут по всему миру. Селиться в непосредственной близи крупных водных объектов они избегали.
А лебедь на Байкале весьма редкая птица.

Ладно, проехали. К Пушкину все равно это не имеет отношения.

Answer (score 3):

Возможно имеется в виду кокошник, который во времена Пушкина был непременным атрибутом свадебного наряда в народной свадьбе. Свадебный кокошник обшивали жемчугом и зачастую более дорогими камнями ("звезда во лбу"). Не брезговали в кокошнике ходить и дамы высшего общества (на картине изображена жена Николая I Александра Федоровна). Правда почему "под", а не "над" косой не знаю, возможно архаичная форма или под в значении "к" (*подплечники, под это платье подходит...*). Других украшений похожих на месяц на Руси не использовали.

[image]

---

Добавлено после ответа Людмилы.

Последние две ссылки в её ответе вряд ли заслуживают хоть малейшего внимания. Не думаю, что имеет смысл всерьёз  обсуждать изображение ауры ясновидящих, а также славян как потомков греческих титанов в Пушкинском творчестве.

[Первая](http://pushkinu1.narod.ru/9.html) ссылка поинтересней, хотя притянутости за уши там тоже немало.  Но стоящие мысли тоже присутствуют. В частности ссылка на запись сказки о царе Салтане в Литовской ССР в 1952-53 гг. записанную в ходе фольклорной экспедиции у местного русского населения (проживающего среди литовцев с XVII-XVIII вв. в отрыве от основной массы русского населения). Цитирую (выделено мной):

> А третья гаварит: вот я бы ему сына радила - **ва лбу сонце, в затылке месяц**, ноги па калена в золате, руки па лактях в земчигах, адна валасинка сяребряная, другая залатая, а тело как в звездочках

Т.е. Месяц и солнце  здесь выступают не более чем метафоры. Что-то вроде красив как день и ночь. Видимо творческая переработка Пушкиным данного образа и стала основой для описания царевны.

Answer (score 2):

Речь не о нарядах и украшениях.В волшебных сказках всех времен и народов мы видим  остатки древнейшего тотемного мировоззрения.
  Тотем "лебедь" заимствован бурятами у тюркоязычных племен. В башкирском фольклоре тоже лебедь является тотемом и бытует понятие, что все лебеди - потомки небесного божества Хумай, прародительницы башкир.
http://pushkinu1.narod.ru/9.html

Образ лебедя в русской и славянской мифологии связан со светлым и радостным началом.   Царевна Лебедь Пушкина олицетворяет  древнее светоносное Божество. Пушкин ничего не прибавил и не убавил к неувядающим народным представлениям о прекрасной волшебной Деве с горящей звездой во лбу, чья вселенская предназначенность выражается в следующих космических функциях: 
     Днем свет белый затмевает,  Ночью землю освещает,  Месяц под косой блестит,  А во лбу звезда горит.

http://www.global-project.ru/hyperborea/zagadki_rusevera3.html

"Светоносность" божеств объясняется современными философами как светящаяся аура. 
Вот у А.Херсонова:. http://eikenclub.ru/nepoznannoe/10785-a-vo-lbu-zvezda-gorit.html

Comment: Людмила, это всё - весьма и весьма здорово, но с какого боку тут буряты???

Comment: А это к тому, что тотем "лебедь" в наших сказках - не наша древность, а образ тюркоязычного фольклора, пришедший к нам из бурятских сказок. Пушкин в своих сказках часто совмещал фольклорные  образы разных народов.

Comment: Ну дык...
Лебедь - национальный символ ирландцев...
И что с того...
Вот там по ссылке Марк Из есть явное "подражание" сказке Пушкина (#2 в спмске) - вот это было бы интереснее... Но опять же, очень сомнительно, что это "первоисточник", а не заимствование из русских сказок.

Answer (score 1):

Возможно, месяц под косой символизирует ослепительно-золотистый цвет волос.

Comment: Кстати, очень даже подходит. Желтый лоб - солнце и металлический блеск волос - месяц.

Answer (score 1):

Находки при раскопках корун, венков, венцов и венчиков, т. е. девических головных уборов X—XIII вв., хотя и редки, но позволяют составить представление о них. Узкая полоска металла или материи охватывала лоб и скреплялась на затылке. Более сложный, богато украшенный венчик назывался «коруна». Изображение коруны можно найти в Изборнике Святослава 1073 г. («Дева» из знаков Зодиака). Коруна представляла собой жесткую основу, обтянутую тканью (иногда под ткань подкладывался валик), и своеобразно украшалась. Коруны чаще всего служили праздничными уборами незамужних женщин-горожанок, сельские жительницы до замужества носили чаще девичьи венцы. Различают три осповных варианта венцов: пластинчатый (серебряный, реже бронзовый); налобный венец-повязка из парчовой, а иногда и шерстяной или полотняной ткани, вышитый и богато орнаментированный; венец из металлических бляшек, нанизанных на нити или шнуры. Девичий венец был своеобразным украшением девичьей прически: нередко от венца у висков заплетались две косички, которые продевались потом в височные кольца; другой вариант — венец поддерживал волосы, уложенные в виде петли, спускавшейся перед ухом от виска (в этом случае волосы как бы «подстилали» височные украшения). Налобный девичий венец, сделанный из ленты, нередко украшался шерстяной бахромой (очевидно, в комплекте с одеждой — шерстяной юбкой-поневой), что подтверждает женское захоронение из кургана вятичей XIII в.12
Украшения древнерусских девичьих корун и налобных венчиков свидетельствуют, что эта форма головных уборов возникла из цветочных венков. Гирлянда из цветов на голове девушки была также символом совершеннолетия и непорочности. Художественные украшения - коруны были призваны создать впечатление венка из живых цветов: отдельные элементы выгибались, делались рельефными, украшались цветными стекляшками, а при достаточном богатстве семьи — драгоценностями ^ Фландрский рыцарь Гильбер де Лануа, побывавший в Новгороде в 1413 г., отметил, что здесь «девушки имеют диадему на макушке, как у святых...». Интересное описание такой «диадемы», т. е. девичьего венца «з городы» (с зубцами), содержится и в духовной Верейского князя Михаила Андреевича: «...венец з городы, да с яхонты, да с лалы (рубинами.— Н. П.), да з зерны с велики[мн] (жемчугом.— Н. П.); другой венок низан великим жомчугом, рясы с яхонты да с лалы, колтки золоты с яхонты...  http://www.bibliotekar.ru/polk-11/21.htm  Женщины Древней Руси.

Answer (score 1):

Царевна-лебедь у Пушкина – трудолюбива и покладиста. "Во влбу звезда горит" означает, что девушка встает рано утром, с первой звездой, а "месяц под косой" – что ложится поздно ночью, когда месяц/луна уже светит на небе во всю силу.

Comment: Не нужно выделять весть текст. Это плохо смотрится и противоречит общепринятым нормам.

Answer (score 0):

Я предполагаю, что ***месяц под косой*** символизирует женскую энергию. Она — под косой, и таким образом женщина может управлять своей лунной энергией (так скажем, приструнить).
А ***во лбу звезда горит*** говорит, скорее всего, о том, что она своего рода "бизнес-леди" или такая сильная женщина — по женски.
Насколько я знаю, солнце — это мужская энергия, луна — женская, а звезда — сила женщины в её, я бы сказала, бизнесе либо профессии. И такие женщины могут совмещать и профессию, и семью — по-женски.

Answer (score 0):

Месяц под косой — это мусульманское украшение. Вот и отгадка. Дева была особенной красоты, потому что вообще она не была русской.
А звезда во лбу — тюркское женское украшение, диадема. Обязательно изготавливалась с камнем в середине.

А Лебедь она потому, что женственна была.

Особая. Необыкновенная. Шамаханская царица.

Comment: Отгадки - это в детский журнал. А здесь надо бы обосновать.

Answer (score 0):

и все Вы  не угадали, Пушкин  просто пересказал старый миф в стихах, это почти  точное  описание древней дохристианской, доегипетской богини рассвета,  которая  разными народами изображалась как "Женщина с рогами, символизирующую полумесяц во время осеннего равноденствия, иногда держит в руках крестообразный жезл(анкр) или плачет стоя на лунном серпе связана с Луной и Венерой изображалась в окружении львов и лебедей.

Comment: Если возражаете, то делайте это в своих Комментариях. Касательно ответа, уместно будет повторить здесь это замечание от behemothus 11 дек '16: «Прошу формулировать ответ более понятно, здесь не конкурс чтения мыслей на расстоянии. И старайтесь соблюдать правила пунктуации».

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо что подняли эту тему. Но...  всё оказывается на много реальнее и мистичнее, почти без иносказательности. Начну с того что я расследовал тайну гибели экспедиции Дятлова на северном урале, в частности главную гипотезу столкновения группы туристов с лешим или как сейчас говорят со снежным человеком. Так вот, копая в этом направлении я узнал, что великий русский писатель Пушкин, как оказалось, был ещё и путешественником и краеведом, он собирал сказания и легенды народов России. В процессе я нечаянно провёл паралель с Пушкинскими сказками - "там чудеса, там леший бродит, русалка на ветвях сидит". Я навёл справки и к моему изумлению оказалось что на древних европейских картах "Лукоморье" это реальное место (!) и находится оно примерно в той же области, а именно СЕВЕРНЫЙ УРАЛ- СЕВЕРНАЯ СИБИРЬ, примерно район Салехарда. Так вот, там местные манси (те что живут в дали от городов) до сих пор говорят шепотом и с оглядкой, когда разговор заходит о лешем, или как они его называют Менк или Землемер (вероятно из-за размашистой широкой походки). Жуткое создания напоминающее двухметрового дикаря с недюжей физической силой и сверх мощными гипнотическими способностями к внушению и вообще психическому воздействию на восприятие живых существ.
Служащий краеведческого музея Салехарда рассказывал мне, как видел двух леших с горящими как угли глазами на берегу низовья Оби, когда он шел с охоты, они прошли мимо него и только зыркнули на него светящимися глазами, которые буравили на сквозь прямо в душу. Жуткое зрелище. От места гибели туристов это недалеко, да и сообщения о частых встречах с лешим в тех краях северного урала (как раз в те года) были довольно частыми, вероятно тогда был всплеск популяции этих редких существ.

Я тогда у  спросил у него, высказав предположение.

- Слушай, но если леший не выдумка, а реальное антропоморфное существо упомянутое в фольклоре народов северного урала и сибири, то может и некоторые другие персонажи сказок Пушкина тоже реальность а не вымысел?
  Директор посмотрел на меня задумчиво, словно размышляя можно ли мне доверить некую тайну, затем затянул сигарету и сказал.
- Хочешь я покажу тебе Царевну лебедь?
- Как?... В каком смысле?
  Я был явно не готов к такому повороту событий
- В самом что ни на есть в прямом. Но правда издали, в процессе как она по небу передвигается... величаво, словно пава, не спеша то есть.
  Я улыбнулся, вспомнив эти слова из сказки о Царе Салтане, но видя его серьёзное лицо, улыбка медленно сползла с моего лица. Смутное предчувствие шокирующего переворота моего мировоззрения стало проникать холодком в моё сознание.
  -Что ты имеешь в виду?  Как это "показать"? У вас тут что, кроме леших и принцессы лебеди водяться?
- Это не принцесса, это Богиня. Возможно раньше она была человеком, но на данном этапе уровень её духовного развития почти Бог. Она не одна такая на Земле, это смотрители и регулировщики развития планеты.
- Эээ...может ты имеешь в виду инопланетян?
  Неуверенно сказал я, пытаясь подправить собеседника с исторического сленга на современный. Но директор только презрительно фыркнул, будто я сказал не об инопланетянах а о тараканах.
- Всякие там инопланетяне по сравнению с ней такие же жалкие туристы как и мы, только на летающих консервных банках. Но манси об этой богине знают больше чем я, они называют её "Золотая баба" или Сорни-най или Зарни-инь, короче говоря богиня утренней зари, которая тем не менее остаётся женщиной, а значит вполне может пойти на романтический контакт с приглянувшимся мужчиной, как и было описано в сказке о Царе Салтане. То есть она может быть и светящейся субстанцией, а может быть и плотью. При этом то что я тебе покажу в точности совпадает с описанием манси о ней. Подойди сюда...
  Директор жестом пригласил меня к компьютеру и усадил в кресло.
- Сейчас я покажу тебе видео Принцессы лебедь, снято работниками ДПС, один из них мой знакомый, копия отправлена в первый отдел (ФСБ)
  Я почувствовал как у меня стал дёргаться глаз. ДПС, ФСБ и принцесса Лебедь в одном предложении звучит на столько гротескно, что как-то совсем не вяжется. Я открыл было рот что то спросить, но директор нажал на воспроизведение видео...

Только посмотрев видео до меня окончательно дошла фраза Пушкина описывающая принцессу лебедь "месяц под косой блестит, а во лбу звезда горит..."

Запись эту мне по понятным причинам не дали. Но! К счастью на просторах ютуба я нечаянно увидел её снова, полёт принцессы лебедь, но в других видеозаписях, вероятно снято другими очевидцами на урале. Так что уважаемые, ваше любопытство я с удовольствием удовлетворю и предоставляю вам воочию убедится в том, что мы живём в поистине таинственном мире, о котором мы ещё так мало знаем...

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VfAlLPkpFM8